# PAF Installation issue in Windows 10

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

While installing PAF, I am getting an error message `"curl is not recognized"` with OS version windows 10. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the OS is windows 10 and curl command is not recognized, then search for curl.exe from run command and copy the path of curl and add it in path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).